# Nested Percentage Height Divs

Tags: css, html, percentage

I need a parent div to automatically resize when it's children do.

The two children have their heights based on percentages.

Code:
http://jsfiddle.net/gBWUv/2/

If you add a height to the parent div, the children show up, but I'd like it to auto size to the children. It's because the children base their height on it's parent, and when the parent doesn't have a height, the children height is then 0. Is there a way to accomplish what I want without javascript? I have a javascript solution, but I hate coding more than is needed. Simple is best.

Here is the less elegant javascript that does exactly what I want:
http://jsfiddle.net/gBWUv/14/

Answer (score 1):

If the parent is zero and the children are 60% height of the parent they would also be zero.  You could make the parent's height 100%?

```
#parent {
    padding: 5% 0;
    background: #000;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, adding a defined height at all to the parent wouldn't work because I have content above and below that parent in the design. It has to dynamically change with the children.

Comment: does or could something have a min-size?  I'm not following why you're showing the div if it's empty.

Comment: @AarenHofferth You may want to read up on the [`height` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property): "Specifies a percentage height. The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value computes to 'auto'"

Comment: I know about the height property, and am aware it computes as 0 for children currently. Perhaps I'm not explaining it well enough. Here is the jQuery solution I had made which does exactly what I want. I'd just rather not have to use it if there is a better, more elegant solution: http://jsfiddle.net/gBWUv/14/